# Python - switch alternative for non-discrete comparisons

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

Maybe this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it.
I am trying to implement something that determines what range a given value is in. In this example, x may be any real number.

```
def f(x):
    if x < 0.1:
        do_something_1()
    elif 0.1 <= x < 1:
        do_something_2()
    elif 1 <= x < 10:
        do_something_3()
    elif x >= 10:
        do_something_4()
```

...you get the idea.

I've seen plenty of examples of dictionaries replacing switch statements in Python, but I've always understood dictionaries as indexing discrete values.

I find it hard to believe that the if-elif-else chain is the best solution in this situation. Does anyone know of a better one?

Comment: I really don't see how, say, C's `switch` statement would improve this code.  Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Best solution in term of what ? speed ? readability ? ...

Comment: I'm not a seasoned C expert, but wouldn't you be able to do, for example, `case 0.1 <= x < 1`? I know it's not much less typing but I feel the intent of the code is clearer. Maybe I've misunderstood how `switch` works.

Comment: @poorsod: No, you can't.  And even if you could, how is `case 0.1 <= x < 1` better than `elif 0.1 <= x < 1`?

Comment: -1 This doesn't really amount to a question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-bisect.html) package to find the index where the value lies, and then call the appropriate function. In your example:

```
import bisect

def f(x):
    funcs = [do_something_1, do_something_2, do_something_3, do_something_4]
    funcs[bisect.bisect_left([.1, 1, 10], x)]()
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of `bisect`.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to improve this is not to repeat the lower bounds.  Your code is equivalent to

```
if x < 0.1:
    do_something_1()
elif x < 1:
    do_something_2()
elif x < 10:
    do_something_3()
else:
    do_something_4()
```

If there are really many values, you might want to `bisect` instead, but with only four options, the above code is probably the best solutuion, at least in terms of readability and speed.

Comment: The example above was just an example; there are 26 ranges I need to split into! I don't want to subject anyone reading the code to having to wade through 26 `elif`s.

Comment: @poorsod: different solutions are appropriate for different regimes because they scale differently.  If you give an abbreviated example -- which is fine, btw! -- then please mention the sizes involved in your real problem too.

Comment: @poorsod: Do those 26 ranges have a pattern?  Or are they defined by arbitrary constants?  If the former, use the pattern to simplify the code.  If the latter, use `bisect`.

Comment: @poorsod: What is the problem that requires splitting into 26 ranges? Just curious.

Comment: I'm working on some code that repackages the SCPI instructions for a bunch of laboratory instruments in a more user-friendly way (the SCPI syntax is a big pain!). This code will be for selecting the sensitivity of an instrument - the function accepts a maximum voltage, and then chooses the range that best accounts for your maximum.

Comment: Is the code in each of the 26 cases truly different (each calling different functions and setting different variables), or is there repeated logic? Does each case just set some other variable to a certain value or something simple like that?

Comment: @poorsod: You actually did not answer my question, so you might be missing the best option.  Using `bisect` is only the right solution if the boundaries between the ranges are arbitrary constants that do not follow any pattern.  If they do follow a pattern, using this pattern would be much better than using `bisect`.

Comment: Sorry, I've been attending to something else for the last hour. @Sven Marnach: The allowed maximum values are 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, etc. So there is a pattern, though it doesn't quite follow a smooth log curve. I'll have a think about how to implement that.

Comment: @David Robinson - yes, it'll be setting a variable to a certain integer between 0 and 25, and then sending that to the device.

Comment: !! Then why don't you just have `val = bisect.bisect_left(x, boundaries)` instead of running separate code for each?

Comment: @David Robinson This is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. Note that even if you hadn't heard of bisect, this would have best been solved in a for loop over the boundaries, comparing each to `x` and keeping track of an index, rather than a 26-clause if/elif statement. This is a great example of an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, using a dict and for loop:

```
ranges_dict = {
    0.1: do_something1,
    1.0: do_something2,
    10.0: do_something3,
    }

for range_val, do_function in sorted(ranges_dict.items()):
    if x < range_val:
        do_function()
        break
else:
    do_something_else()
```